# Insert or Update in one table from inserted in another table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need help to do this:

```
TABLE POSITION
ID, int (PK)
SN, varchar(10)
Lat, double
Lon, double
etc...

TABLE ACTUAL_POSITION
SN, varchar(10) (PK)
Lat, double
Lon, double
```

When records are inserted in the first table, corresponding (by SN) record should be updated in the second table. If no SN record is found in that table, it should be created.

Multiple records are inserted in the first table at the same time, even for the same SN, so I need to extract the very last Lat and Lon for every single SN (when vehicles are out of connection range they buffer the data to send and then send it all togheter, so the receiving sw writes into sql in a single pass) from the inserted table.

Comment: How do you define "the very last"? A table is an unordered set of rows, so you need to define what you mean by "last" and there needs to be some way to figure that out from the data. Imagine dumping a bag of marbles on the floor, and then asking someone who just came in the room which marble hit the floor last?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.SummarizePosition
ON dbo.Position
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    ;WITH x AS 
    (
      SELECT SN, Lat, Long, 
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SN 
        ORDER BY ID DESC) -- or by timestamp col desc
      FROM inserted
      WHERE EXISTS
      ( SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Actual_Position AS p
        WHERE p.SN = inserted.SN
      )
    )
    UPDATE p
      SET p.Lat = x.Lat,
      p.Lon = x.Lon
      FROM dbo.Actual_Position AS p
      INNER JOIN x ON x.sn = p.sn
      WHERE x.rn = 1;

    ;WITH x AS 
    (
      SELECT SN, Lat, Long, /* other cols, */
       rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SN 
       ORDER BY ID DESC) -- or by timestamp col desc
      FROM inserted
      WHERE NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Actual_Position AS p
        WHERE p.SN = inserted.SN
      )
    )
    INSERT dbo.Actual_Position(SN, Lat, Long /*, other cols */)
      SELECT SN, Lat, Lon /*, other cols */
       FROM x
       WHERE rn = 1;
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a trigger to update ACTUAL_POSITION every time a new row is inserted in POSITION.

For more information on triggers in SQL Server 2005, see [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx).

Comment: The problem is if there are two rows with the same SN, which row goes into `ACTUAL_POSITION`? Needs to define how to determine "last row"...

Comment: I assume the OP means chronologically, in which case I believe a trigger would suffice. Also, although he did not provide the entire table definition, I suppose there is a timestamp column somewhere in there.

Comment: I was thinking just about inserction order... but, if it's better, among the "etc" columns I've got also a (unix) timestamp column, so I could consider "the last row" (always per SN) the one with the bigger timestamp